# query on FIND_IN_SET

Tags: mysql, find-in-set

The following query

```
SELECT ASSOCIATED_RISK 
FROM PROJECT_ISSUES
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('98',ASSOCIATED_RISK);
```

returns output as

```
96,98

90,98
```

but if I use

```
SELECT ASSOCIATED_RISK
FROM PROJECT_ISSUES 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('96,98',ASSOCIATED_RISK);
```

it doesn't returns anything.In this case I would like to retrieve the first row.

```
96,98
```

Comment: First of all normalize your structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment:

> is there any other way I can get it in single query instead of framing multiple `find_in_set` and concat them

As an alternative solution, you can use `locate` on your `ASSOCIATED_RISK` value.

***Example***:

```
locate( replace( '96,98', ',', '' ), replace( ASSOCIATED_RISK, ',', '' ) )
```

**Edit**:
As per `Aziz Shaikh` comment, we can see that there is a possibility of *true* result though the search string not existing in the target string.

As an alternative solution, you can replace the search string from target string with an empty string and compare the lengths. If original string's length is grater than new replaced string, then it is a *found true* result.

***Example***:

```
-- this should be greater than 0 for a found true
length( ASSOCIATED_RISK ) > length( replace( ASSOCIATED_RISK, '96,98', '' ) )
```

Comment: @user1650864 this works but do watch out if `ASSOCIATED_RISK` contains a value which is something like this `'9698,97'`, the above query will also return `'9698,97'` because it is replace the `,` and searching as a string.

Comment: @AzizShaikh: You are right. Alternative solution is replace the search string with empty in target string and compare the lengths with `>` for *found true*.

Comment: @user1650864: There is a bug found in my solution suggested. I have updated with an alternative.

Comment: @Ravinder will the `length` part be used with the `locate` part using an `AND` ?

Comment: @AzizShaikh: We can, but it depends on the necessity to use. As you already pointed out a possible issue, I suggest not to depend on `locate(replace(...` solution.

Comment: Some observation on various queries.

SELECT ASSOCIATED_RISK FROM PROJECT_ISSUES WHERE LOCATE( REPLACE( '96,98', ',', '' ), REPLACE( ASSOCIATED_RISK, ',', '' ) );
returns one value
96,98

but if i use reverse search SELECT ASSOCIATED_RISK FROM PROJECT_ISSUES WHERE LOCATE( REPLACE( '98,96', ',', '' ), REPLACE( ASSOCIATED_RISK, ',', '' ) );
it doesn't return record.


However the below works in either way
SELECT * FROM PROJECT_ISSUES WHERE FIND_IN_SET('98',ASSOCIATED_RISK) AND FIND_IN_SET('96',ASSOCIATED_RISK);

Comment: No. `Find_in_set` returns true only if found in sequential order. For reverse order search, it won't work. You need to opt a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `AND` clause, like this:

```
SELECT ASSOCIATED_RISK 
FROM PROJECT_ISSUES 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('96',ASSOCIATED_RISK)
AND FIND_IN_SET('98',ASSOCIATED_RISK)
```

Your query is failing because `FIND_IN_SET()` does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (",") character. Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set. In your case, the first argument is `'96,98'`, so it fails.

Comment: This gives the proper result.However is there any other way I can get it in single query instead of framing multiple find_in_set and concat them ?

Comment: @user1650864 sorry, I dont think it is possible unless you can change the table structure. Ideally comma separated values should not be stored in a database column

Answer (score 0):

This will Give result. see the difference.

```
SELECT ASSOCIATED_RISK FROM PROJECT_ISSUES WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ASSOCIATED_RISK,'96,98');
```

Comment: sorry.This too didn't give the result.

Comment: In this basically, as i found that syntax was incorrect. use my query. gives surely yours expected result :) Thank you.

Comment: I can't think. gives yours schema i will give yours result. by using single FIND_IN_SET function we can fetch multiple result of comma separated values.